# Exporting a conda environment to a yaml file won't let me rebuild it on the same machine

Tags: python, conda

I have a working conda environment that I want to share with a colleague who is working on the same computer cluster. I exported my environment to a YAML file but then I cannot recreate the environment using that YAML file again due to incompatible packages. The full error message is:

---

*Could not solve for environment specs.*

*The following packages are incompatible*

- alsa-lib 1.2.6.1**  is requested and can be installed;
- click 8.1.3**  is installable with the potential options

  - click 8.1.3,    which can be installed;
  - click 8.1.3 would require    __win  , which is missing on the system;
- dask 2022.2.0**  is uninstallable because it requires

  - distributed >=2022.2.0,<2022.2.1.0a0 , which requires

    - click >=6.6,<8.1.0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    - openssl    !=1.1.1e , which can be installed;
      distributed 2022.2.0** , which    cannot be installed (as previously explained);
- gst-plugins-base 1.20.3**  is installable with the potential options

  - gst-plugins-base 1.20.3, which can be installed;
  - gst-plugins-base 1.20.3 would require

    - alsa-lib >=1.2.7.2,<1.2.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable    versions previously reported;
- icu 69.1**  is requested and can be installed;
- openssl 3.0.5**  is requested and can be installed;
- qt 5.12.9**  is uninstallable because there are no viable options

  - qt 5.12.9 would require

    - openssl <3 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
  - qt 5.12.9 would require

    - icu >=67.1,<68.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
  - qt 5.12.9 would require

    - icu >=68.1,<69.0a0 ,    which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
  - qt 5.12.9 would require

    - gst-plugins-base >=1.18.5,<1.19.0a0  but there are no viable options

      - gst-plugins-base 1.18.5 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
      - gst-plugins-base 1.18.5 would require

        - alsa-lib >=1.2.3,<1.2.4.0a0 , which conflicts with any    installable versions previously reported.

---

Why is this happening? How can a working conda environment have incompatible packages?

- I start with a working conda environment.
- I try to create the environment on the same system.
- My YAML file has both the default and the conda-forge channel.
- I tried installing the conda environment both from a `--no-build` YAML file and a full YAML file but both had incompatible packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conda env export` function doesn’t capture channels of origin properly for any *ad hoc* commands that may have used a `-c` flag when mutating the environment. Rather, it simply captures the current user configuration of channels (including any environment-specific ones in the *active* environment, which is not necessarily the exported one!). Moreover, solving is context-sensitive to the `channel_priority` setting. E.g., `strict` mode can cause packages from channels to be masked. That is, it is entirely feasible to go through a series of *ad hoc* install commands that switch channel priority in such a way that the final set of packages could not be installed from a single YAML with just one strict channel priority.

Since you are on the same system, there should definitely be a path forward to recreating the exact environment.

First, make sure that channel_priority is “flexible”. Second, have a look through the `conda list` output for the environment and make sure that all the channels listed there are included in the YAML.

A more strict recreation strategy that can be used when working on the same system is `conda list --explicit`.

---

Longer term, one can adopt more reproducible package management practices by always working from a YAML definition from the start. That is, avoid *ad hoc* mutations of the environment and instead always use `conda env {create,update}` commands.

A newer solution in this space is `conda-lock`, which literally presolves environments and includes just the URLs needed for download.

Comment: Thank you very much @merv, the `conda list --explicit` did the job! I will work directly from a YAML-definition from now on!